# Why can't I clear my image cache?

Tags: magento, caching, magento-1.9

For some reason I cannot clear the images for this product.
http://avfgroup.com/jnl454 or any other product on my website.

The cache shows the old image - yet I cant delete it as it just coems straight back, my external images url points at the correct image.

I have also tried to delete the images in magento which also doesn't work.
I have cleared all caches and re-indexed and nothing seems to work?

We use toybananas External URL extension which points at the correct images.

Please help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you use Flat product index and the index is not up to date. In the flat tables the old image is referred.
Rebuild your index (while you are at it, you can rebuild all the indexes) and clear the image cache after the indexes are rebuilt.

Comment: done that. i have to rebuild my index every time i add a new CSV import - nothing works.